# Use of uninitialized value $oldvalue in concatenation (.) or string error in perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

i want to check old value and new value is match or not , but i got the error as follows,

```
Use of uninitialized value $oldvaluein concatenation (.) or string
```

i find the $row[0] will be return empty or NULL or string ,any suggestion to fix it.?

```
my $newvalue = $2;
my $oldvalue;
my $select_sth3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT oldname FROM `Description` des,Devices D where D.hid = des.hid and D.ipv4 = '$ip'  and des.index = $index ")or die "$dbh->errstr";
$select_sth3->execute() or die "$dbh->errstr";
my @row = $select_sth3->fetchrow_array;
$oldvalue= $row[0];
if ($newvalue ne $oldvalue)
  {
      print "$newvalue \n";
      print "$oldvalue\n";
      .......and .update database...
  }
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings; `!

Comment: i have use strict; in my code

Comment: What's the result of: `print Dumper(\@row);`?

Comment: When you prepare, you really should use `?` and supply the variables to the `execute` call. like this: `$select3 = $dbh->prepare("… and D.ipv4 = ? and and des.index = ? ") or die $dbh->errstr; $select3->execute($ip, $index)…` avoid SQL injections, even if you are sure, just to get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$oldvalue` is defined before you do string compare.

```
if (defined($oldvalue)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Xu Ding, i had follow your method ,but no print

Comment: if (defined($oldvalue)) {
    print "$oldvalue\n";
}

Comment: but i am sure return value have string

Answer (score 0):

mention in if condition like this....

```
if (($oldvalue ne '') or (!defined($oldvalue)) or ($newvalue ne $oldvalue)){
//place your code here...
}
```